# C++ Stacks with multiple values

Tags: c++, templates, stack

I have some code below.  This code is a basic push/pop stack class that I have created as a template to enable someone to push/pop stacks.  I have a homework assignment and what I am trying to do now is create a stack that has multiple values.

So I want to be able to create a stack that basically can be sent three integers and where I can push/pop these as well.  What I am looking for is the theory on how this should work and I am not trying to get someone to do my homework for me.

The scenario is that we are dealing with parts.  So the user will put in the serial number (int), manufacture date (int), and lotnum (int).  So my questions are:

1. When I "pop" the value should I attempt to send all three of the values during the pop or handle this another way?
2. Should I try to create a new class using the struct like the class or something else?

   ```
   /****************************************************************************
   Inventory class.

   Chad Peppers

   This class creates a object for stacking nodes

   In addition, there should be member functions to perform the following 
   operations:
   - Push to the stack
   - Pop to the stack
   - Function to check if empty

   ****************************************************************************/
   // Specification file for the DynIntStack class

   template <class T>
   class Inventory
   {
   private:
      // Structure for stack nodes
      struct StackNode
      {
         T value;        // Value in the node
         StackNode *next;  // Pointer to the next node
      };

      StackNode *top;      // Pointer to the stack top

   public:
      // Constructor
      Inventory()
         {  top = NULL; }

      // Destructor
      ~Inventory();

      // Stack operations
      void push(T);
      void pop(T &);
      bool isEmpty();
   }; 

   /*************************************************************************
   Basic class constructor.

   Input Parameters:  Information to build the  stack

   Return Type:  void

   *************************************************************************/

   template<class T>
   Inventory<T>::~Inventory()
   {
      StackNode *nodePtr, *nextNode;

      // Position nodePtr at the top of the stack.
      nodePtr = top;

      // Traverse the list deleting each node.
      while (nodePtr != NULL)
      {
         nextNode = nodePtr->next;
         delete nodePtr;
         nodePtr = nextNode;
      }
   }

   /*************************************************************************
   Function to push an item in the stack

   Input Parameters:  T

   Return Type:  void

   *************************************************************************/

   template<class T>
   void Inventory<T>::push(T num)
   {
      StackNode *newNode; // Pointer to a new node

      // Allocate a new node and store num there.
      newNode = new StackNode;
      newNode->value = num;

      // If there are no nodes in the list
      // make newNode the first node.
      if (isEmpty())
      {
         top = newNode;
         newNode->next = NULL;
      }
      else  // Otherwise, insert NewNode before top.
      {
         newNode->next = top;
         top = newNode;
      }
   }

   /*************************************************************************
   Function to pop an item in the stack

   Input Parameters:  T

   Return Type:  void

   *************************************************************************/
   template<class T>
   void Inventory<T>::pop(T &num)
   {
      StackNode *temp; // Temporary pointer

      // First make sure the stack isn't empty.
      if (isEmpty())
      {
         cout << "The stack is empty.\n";
      }
      else  // pop value off top of stack
      {
         num = top->value;
         temp = top->next;
         delete top;
         top = temp;
      }
   }

   /*************************************************************************
   Basic class deconstructor.

   Input Parameters:  None

   Return Type:  void

   *************************************************************************/
   template<class T>
   bool Inventory<T>::isEmpty()
   {
      bool status;

      if (!top)
         status = true;
      else
         status = false;

      return status;
   }
   ```

Comment: You could simplify your isEmpty() by using only return (!top).

Comment: You could also economize the push, by using push(const T&). In this case you will not construct a temporary value, while calling this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could create a struct which is aggregate of the 3 int values and then instantiate    template Inventory for that struct somthing on these lines

```
#include "Inventory.h"
//create an aggregate structure
struct ProductData {
   int serial_num;
   int manufacture_date;
   int lot_num;
}

//instantiate Inventory for ProductData

Inventory<ProductData> stack;
```

Comment: This sounds like a great approach let me give this one a try!